# How to resize the Bottom Dock Area

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a Qt app with the following layout, where the bottom dock-area extends under the right dock-area. This is the default when adding Dock widgets to both side and bottom areas.

```
+-----------------+-----+
|                 | DW1 |
|     CW          +-----+
|                 | DW2 |
+-----------------+-----+
|  DW3                  |
+-----------------------+
```

I would like to instead have the right dock-area extend down to the bottom beside the bottom dock area as such:

```
+-----------------+-----+
|                 | DW1 |
|     CW          +-----+
|                 | DW2 |
+-----------------+     |
|  DW3            |     |
+-----------------------+
```

This should be simple, but I have searched the documentation and asked almighty Google, without success. I am not adding a code sample, since this is more of a general API question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`QMainWindow::setCorner`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCorner)...

```
QMainWindow main_window;
main_window.setCorner(Qt::BottomRightCorner, Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
```

That *should* associate the bottom right corner with the right hand dock area -- haven't tested though.